# BigQuery Audit Logs - selecting keys with @ sign from JSON metadata

Tags: sql, json, google-bigquery

When creating a Log Explorer queries, we can use the following syntax:

```
protoPayload.metadata."@type"="type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.BigQueryAuditMetadata"
```

Adter having created a sink to put all logs into BigQuery, I'm trying to select the type with the following code:

```sql
JSON_EXTRACT(PARSE_JSON(protopayload_auditlog.metadataJson), '$.@type')
```

But it returns an error `Unsupported operator in JSONPath: @;` How do I do that? Here's a sample payload:

```json
{
  "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.BigQueryAuditMetadata",
  "tableDataRead": {
    "fields": [
      "insertId",
      "logName",
      "protopayload_auditlog.metadataJson",
      "protopayload_auditlog.methodName",
      "receiveTimestamp",
      "resource.labels.dataset_id",
      "resource.labels.location",
      "resource.labels.project_id",
      "resource.type",
      "severity"
    ],
    "jobName": "projects/element-analytics-dev-poc/jobs/job_XvacfHSAAr_Og7zQFVNV9ioV9vfu",
    "reason": "JOB"
  }
}
```

I would like to know how to query the JSON in BigQuery to get the value of `@type`?

Comment: Can you confirm whether your question is about fetching values of "@type" or “protopayload\_auditlog.metadataJson"  from the BigQuery table?

Comment: I added a clarification at the end. I would like to know how to get the `@type` using JSON_ExTRACT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  `"$['@type']"` for your JSONPath as in below example

```
WITH data AS (
  SELECT '''
{
  "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.BigQueryAuditMetadata",
  "tableDataRead": {
    "fields": [
      "insertId",
      "logName",
      "protopayload_auditlog.metadataJson",
      "protopayload_auditlog.methodName",
      "receiveTimestamp",
      "resource.labels.dataset_id",
      "resource.labels.location",
      "resource.labels.project_id",
      "resource.type",
      "severity"
    ],
    "jobName": "projects/element-analytics-dev-poc/jobs/job_XvacfHSAAr_Og7zQFVNV9ioV9vfu",
    "reason": "JOB"
  }
}
  ''' AS json
)
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(json, "$['@type']") AS type
FROM data
```

with output

[image]

Comment: Oh geez, I would never figure this one out. Is it just a standard way of getting JSON out that has these special character? Tried to Google it a lot